# Adding a file description while uploading a file

Tags: php, file-upload, field-description

I've created a basic upload form and everything works fine to upload, but I'm unable to find a way to add the file description to the page. I'd like it to go here under "Description":
[uploads page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUpmU.png)

HTML Form:

```
<form action="/scripts/upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select a file to upload:
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"><br />
    <textarea id="FileDescription" name="FileDescription" rows="1" placeholder="*File description" required></textarea> <br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
```

Script:

```
<?php
$target_dir  = "../uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk    = 1;
$df          = disk_free_space("../uploads/");

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = filesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > $df) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file " . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]) . " has 
been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: the image shows a jpeg image and an html file... is the html file the comment?

Comment: Do you mean you wish the description to appear in the apache directory listing of the directory ??

Comment: The form is the HTML page I'm using. The photo is just showing the upload page where the files and description should go. The files on there are just what I used to test if I had it working. Edit: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11792/description-column-in-apaches-directory-listing

Answer (score -1):

The `<textarea>` tag must be linked to the form.
Use it this way:

```
<form action="/scripts/upload.php" id="myForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select a file to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"><br />
    <textarea id="FileDescription" form="myForm" name="FileDescription" rows="1" placeholder="*File description" required></textarea> <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
</form>
```

Only then, the content of the texarea is transferred. You can access the description then with `$_POST["FileDescription"]`. To use it as the Apache description, see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html#adddescription